# undefined method tag_counts_on for Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

I am using the acts_as_taggable_on gem: https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on

and I am trying to show the tags on certain posts but it throws an error:

```
undefined method `tag_counts_on' for #<Array:0x007fa5d4ac3088>
```

View:

```
<% tag_cloud @vote_feed_items.tag_counts_on(:tags).order('count desc').limit(15), %w[a b c] do |tag, css_class| %>
   <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag.name), class: css_class %>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@vote_feed_items = @user.vote_feed
```

UserModel:

```
def vote_feed
  Micropost.unscoped.from_microposts_voted_for_by(self)
end
```

MicropostModel:

```
def self.from_microposts_voted_for_by(user)
  find_by_sql("select m.* from microposts m
        join (SELECT voteable_id, updated_at FROM votes WHERE voter_id = #{user.id} AND voteable_type = 'Micropost') z on z.voteable_id=m.id
        order by z.updated_at desc")
end
```

Is find_by_sql returning an array? If so do I need to write this a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, but if what you want is to return a relation you can do this:

```
def self.from_microposts_voted_for_by(user)
  results = find_by_sql("select m.* from microposts m
        join (SELECT voteable_id, updated_at FROM votes WHERE voter_id = #{user.id} AND voteable_type = 'Micropost') z on z.voteable_id=m.id
        order by z.updated_at desc")
  Micropost.where id: results.map(&:id)
end
```

[find_by_sql returns an array](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Querying.html#method-i-find_by_sql).

## With ActiveRecord::Relation

You could build query using relations, I am not sure about your models, I will assume:

```
class Micropost
  has_many :votes
```

so your method would be more coherent with Rails inside a scope:

```
scope(:voted_by, ->(user) do
  joins(:votes).where('votes.voter_id = ?', user.id).order('votes.updated_at desc')
end)
```

Also you wont hit database eagerly. You would use this scope with something like this:

```
@microposts = Micropost.voted_by current_user
```